# How to persist a Realm List property in Swift 4?

Tags: ios, realm, swift4

Using Swift 4 and Realm 3.0.1, I'd like to store a list of Realm objects in a property of a parent Realm 
object. I ran into the following problem:

In Swift 4, properties that should be persisted into Realm have to be `@objc dynamic`, e.g. `@objc dynamic var id: String = ""`. However, Realm's Array replacement type, `List`, can not be stored that way: `@objc dynamic var children: List<Child>? = nil` causes this compiler error:

> Property cannot be marked @objc because its type cannot be represented in Objective-C

For more context, here's a full example:

```
final class Child: Object {
  @objc dynamic var name: String = ""
}

final class Parent: Object {
  // this fails to compile
  @objc dynamic var children1: List<Child>?

  // this compiles but the children will not be persisted
  var children2: List<Child>?
}
```

So is there another way to store object lists in Realm and Swift 4?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Realm `List`s can never be `nil`, and they don’t need the `@objc dynamic`. They should only be `let`, although I can't find that specifically called out in the documentation, there is a [comment](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/5433#issuecomment-340105425) from a realm contributor that calls it out specifically

There is a [cheat sheet](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#property-cheatsheet) for properties in the [documentation](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/).

```
let dogs = List<Dog>()
```

Comment: how do you change the dogs if it's declared with let?

Comment: @Jan `realm.write { dogs.removeAll(); dogs.append(Dog()) }`. This potentially results in detached dogs. You can do `realm.write { person.dogs.forEach { realm.delete($0) }; person.dogs.append(Dog()) }`. Depends on your situation.

Comment: Realm List documentation states "Unlike Swift’s native collections, Lists are reference types, and are only immutable if the Realm that manages them is opened as read-only." https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/api/Classes/List.html

Comment: @AllenHumphreys Well, just trying to emphasise the mental model that these are not like Swift arrays - mutability is determined by the state of the Realm, not by var/let.

Comment: append() data line has to be inside write block or nothing is saved to List