# RealmSwift initialize list : Cannot specialize a non-generic definition

Tags: swift, list, realm

Hi I have an exception like "Cannot specialize a non-generic definition"
when i'm trying to initialize List in Realm object. Does anyone know how to fix this issue? swift 3.2

```
class Dog: Object {
    @objc dynamic var name = ""
    @objc dynamic var age = 0 
}

class Event : Object{
    dynamic var event_id = 0
    dynamic var date : String?
    dynamic var name : String?
    dynamic var remind : Remind?
    dynamic var event_status = 0

    let dogs = List<Dog>()       "Cannot specialize a non-generic definition"

    required convenience init?(map: Map){ self.init() } 
}
```

Comment: Is it possible you haven't imported `RealmSwift` and that the `List` type exists in another part of your project? You might try: `let dogs = RealmSwift.List<Dog>()`

Comment: No man, I imported :
import Foundation
import UIKit
import Alamofire
import RealmSwift
import ObjectMapper
import ObjectMapper_Realm
import SwiftyJSON
import BFKit

Comment: Thanks a lot, but "RealmSwift.List<Dog>()" is working instead of "List<Dog>()". But in other my project "List<Dog>()" is working well and i was confused.

Comment: It seems like a name conflict then. You'll have to look around for other structs/classes named List.

Comment: Yeah, there is one more struct List :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I wanted to give the solution to this question some context. In Swift, namespacing is [implicit on a module level](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25232124/5099014). If you have external modules, such as RealmSwift, which has a type `List` you can still have a type named `List` in your own module. You can even have multiple external modules with the type `List`.

My reasoning for the error you presented was as follows

1. In Realm, what you posted is exactly [how you're supposed to declare a list](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47180628/5099014)
2. Your example compiled in the context of my project which already uses Realm `List`s
3. The error indicated suggests that the swift compiler knows that `List` is a valid type and in fact knows about a function named `List.init()`, however, the compiler is telling you that the function isn't generic.

The only answer at that point, is to assume the compiler is using a different definition of `List` than you are intending. The only way this happens is if the scope you're in (your project or another type), has also defined a type `List`, since internal types take precedence over external types. This precedence is extended further with type nesting. If you'd like to keep Realm's `List` as the default list, you can nest your `List` in another structure to provide a namespace of sorts.

The following example is as concise as possible given the complex situation.

```
import RealmSwift

let myGlobalDogs = List()
let myGlobalNestedListDogs = MyClass.List()
let globalDogs = RealmSwift.List<Dog>()

class List { }

class MyClass {
    class List { }

    let dogs = RealmSwift.List<Dog>()
    let myNestedListDogs = List() // type: MyModule.MyClass.List
    let myDogs = MyModule.List() // type: MyModule.List
}

class MyOtherClass {

    let dogs = RealmSwift.List<Dog>()
    let myNestedListDogs = MyClass.List() // type: MyModule.MyClass.List
    let myDogs = List() // type: MyModule.List
}
```

Fortunately, types/functions are usually different enough that you can't inadvertently use the wrong one without encountering an error eventually, such as the one you encountered.

Comment: This is great. I've been stuck for hours trying to figure out what to do. I couldn't return what I needed to return on my function. Thanks! +1