# Create array of other model with Realm - SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, realm

I have two models that I want to store in a realm database. They are team and player. Each team will have x number of players and I want these to be accessible through the team. E.g. the user selects a team and then any corresponding players. I want the user in the end to be able to create a new team, create new players and assign players to a team

```
class Team: Object{
    @objc dynamic var teamName: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var players: [Player] = []
}

class Player: Object{
    @objc dynamic var playerName: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var shirtNumber: Int = 0
}
```

How would I then look at accessing these new models and more specifically, what would be a good way of iterating through the teams, and then the players inside.

I am very new to Realm and the concepts of databases inside my app so not really sure where to start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you want to leverage a List object instead of an array to store players in a team:

```
class Team: Object{
    @objc dynamic var teamName: String = ""
    let playerList = List<Player>()
}
```

that will create a one to many relationship (one team has many players).

If you need to traverse from player back to team you can either manually do it with a direct relationship

```
class Player: Object{
    @objc dynamic var playerName: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var shirtNumber: Int = 0
    @objc dynamic var myTeam: Team!
}
```

or you can have Realm manage it for you and automatically create the inverse relationship*

```
class Player: Object{
    @objc dynamic var playerName: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var shirtNumber: Int = 0
    var teams = LinkingObjects(fromType: Team.self, property: "playerList")
}
```

As far as iterating over the teams and players, just a simple for loop will do it

```
let teamResults = realm.objects(Team.self)

for team in teamResults {
   print(team.teamName)
   for player in team.playerList {
       print("  player: \(player.playerName)"
   }
}
```

*note that LinkingObjects is plural. It actually creates a many to many relationship - that means a player could be linked back to several teams. This generally isn't an issue and more a design choice.

Comment: Thank you so much this is a really helpful answer - I am getting the error 'Cannot specialise a non-generic definition' in the line `let playerList = List<Player>()`. Any ideas?

Comment: Changing the code to let playerList = RealmSwift.List<Player>() worked! I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47336691/realmswift-initialize-list-cannot-specialize-a-non-generic-definition)