# How do I use realm on swift to store array of objects?

Tags: objective-c, swift, database, realm

In an earlier question I was asking about how I would be about to store an instance of a class on a local database, and I was suggested to use realm as my method of storage. I've setup my realm and done the research, however, in my class, I have an array of objects and when I try to set the array of objects in to "@objc dynamic" inorder to store it into the realm file, it wouldn't allow be to do so, throwing the error "Property cannot be marked @objc because its type cannot be represented in Objective-C". I don't really understand what this mean or what can be represented in Objective-C".

```
//
//  MealPlan.swift
//  IA
//
//  Created by Ian Dong on 8/25/20.
//  Copyright © 2020 Ian Dong. All rights reserved.
//

import Foundation
import RealmSwift
class MealPlan: Object {
    
    @objc dynamic var ingerdientList: [IngerdientCost] = [];
    var k: Int = 0;
    var serving : Int
    @objc dynamic var cost : [IngerdientCost] = [];
    var name : String;
    
    init ( size: Int, name: String){
        self.serving = size;
        self.name = name;
    }
    func addIngerdient (newIngerdient: IngerdientCost){
        ingerdientList.insert(newIngerdient, at: k);
        k = k+1;
    }
    func removeINgerdient(theIngerdient: IngerdientCost)
    {
        var c: Int = 0;
        while theIngerdient.amount != ingerdientList[c].amount && c <= k
        {
            c=c+1;
        }
        ingerdientList.remove(at: c);
        k=k-1;
    }
    func getCost() -> Array<IngerdientCost>
    {
        var c: Int = 0;
        while c <= ingerdientList.count
        {
            cost[c].ingerdientName = ingerdientList[c].ingerdientName;
            cost[c].amount = ingerdientList[c].amount * Double(serving);
            c = c+1;
        }
        return cost;
    }
    func setServing( serv: Int)
    {
        self.serving = serv;
    }
}
```

```
//
//  Ingerdient cost .swift
//  IA
//
//  Created by Ian Dong on 8/25/20.
//  Copyright © 2020 Ian Dong. All rights reserved.
//

import Foundation
import RealmSwift

class IngerdientCost: Object{
    
    init(Name: Ingerdient, Amount: Double )
    {
        self.amount = Amount;
        self.ingerdientName = Name;
    }
    
    var ingerdientName: Ingerdient;
    var amount: Double;
    
}
```

Comment: `IngerdientCost` must also conform to `Object`

Comment: Also, you should use a `List` instead of array: `var ingerdientList: List<IngerdientCost>()`

Comment: How would I make IngerdientCost conform to Object?

Comment: what would be the difference between list and array?

Comment: `List` is kind of like Realm's alternative to array. You can still do `var numbers = [String]()`, but for your own custom classes, you need to use `List`. Also in my comment above I meant to say `var ingerdientList = List<IngerdientCost>()`

Comment: Your realm objects are missing `self.init()`. See [Models](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#limitations-models) - Custom initializers for Object subclasses section. Also, this is not correct for a realm list object `@objc dynamic var ingerdientList: [IngerdientCost] = [];`. Needs to be `let ingredientList = List<IngredientCost>()`. Take a few minutes and read up on lists in the Realm [Getting Started Guide](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#getting-started)

Answer (score 1):

In Realm, you need to use `List` instead of arrays for custom classes (like `IngerdientCost`). For `List`, you don't use `@objc dynamic`, and it [needs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47180628/14351818) to be declared as `let`.

```
class MealPlan: Object {
    
    let ingerdientList = List<IngerdientCost>() /// no @objc dynamic ! but you need to use let
    var k: Int = 0
    var serving : Int
    let cost = List<IngerdientCost>() /// also no @objc dynamic !
    var name : String

    ...

}
```

Then, `IngerdientCost` needs to conform to `Object`:

```
class IngerdientCost: Object {
    @objc dynamic var ingerdientName: Ingerdient? /// to-one relationships must be optional → https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#relationships
    @objc dynamic var amount = Double(0)
}
```

Most properties and methods of `Array` are available in `List`, like `.count`, and you can loop over it (`for object in ingerdientList {}`).

<sub>On a side note there's no reason to use `;` at the end of each line.</sub>

Comment: but in my code, I use the array properties, would list still work?

Comment: Most things like `for...in` will work. Let me check.

Comment: okay like for example ".count" and array references like "array[c]"

Comment: Here's the [declaration](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/api/Classes/List.html) for `List`. `List` and `Array` both conform to `MutableCollection` which allows you to do `array[c]`, and `List` also conforms to `RealmCollection` (one of Realm's custom types), which has support for `.count`

Comment: I've added the code for the IngerdientCost above, I think I've done what you've told me, but it is still throwing the same error.

Comment: You need to use `@objc dynamic var` for `ingerdientName` and `amount` I think

Comment: And `Ingerdient` will also need to conform to `Object`...

Comment: I've turned all in to subClass of Objects, Ingredient, IngredientCost, and MealPlan

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223561/discussion-between-aheze-and-ian-dong).